# SSRS: How to reduce the number of data labels shown on a graph?

Tags: reporting-services, graph, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

If I run a report running on SSRS / SQL Server 2008 R2, that charts data over a year, with data labels turned on, it looks like this, which is fine:

[image: Data Labels over 1 year]

But when I change the time period of the report to run over 5 years, it looks like this, which is a mess:

[image: Data Labels over 5 years]

Can someone tell me if there is a setting or something to change the maximum number of data labels show.  You can see that SSRS has automatically filtered out many of the dates along the X axis, so that it looks ok; I want the same to happen with the data labels.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to limit the quantity of labels.

The only work around I can suggest is to remove the labels and add a tooltip with the value.  It requires the user to roll over each point, but results in a usable report.

Comment: Thanks.  It's not ideal but I've also made the Visible property of the data label an expression, so that if the date range is > 2 years, Visible = False, otherwise it's true.  This way it hides them when they become an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Calculate row counts which suit in your report. This would be used for limitation for complete shown data labels. For Example: `(countrows("Dataset1")>20)`
20 is the best number of records suits all data labels. Then set another criteria for how many labels which can be shown in high density labels.

For Example: `RowNumber("Dataset1") mod 3 = 0`

```
=iif((countrows("Dataset1")>20),iif((RowNumber("Dataset1") mod 3 = 0),Fields!PercentageOff.Value ,Nothing), Fields!PercentageOff.Value )
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that provides a relevant example of how to work around this omission in SSRS.

Answer (score 3):

There is an option if you are using ssrs 2008 or later, the label visible property can be validated with an IIF or any other logical operator.

Comment: I'm not sure how this got the most votes, without providing an example of how this could be used to implement the OP's request. In any case, it doesn't allow automatic density reduction like the built-in axis labels.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to share an alternative, as I just ran into this issue myself.  For my chart, I have a Series group of "Budget Name", where there are 2 budgets and 1 "Actual".  I wanted to display only the value of the Actual, so I used the following expression for the series label data:
`=iif(Fields!Budget_Name.Value="ACTUAL",SUM(Fields!Amt.Value),Nothing)`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to change it to show a data label for every other data point, and used the below code:

Highlight the data point and in the properties box "Visible" enter

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to change it to show a data label for every other data point, and used the below code:

Highlight the data point and in the properties box `Visible` enter

`=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, True, False)`

This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something to note: If this is for a continuous series you cannot use "RowNumber" as SSRS will only allow distinct values and not aggregates. To limit the value based on a date stamp on the x-axis:
Right click series, show data labels, right click the data label in the chart, data label properties, and change the value to something like this: =iif(Minute(Fields!date_stamp_calculated.Value) = 0, Fields!TrailingTotal.Value, Nothing).

This looks for everything once an hour, you could beef up the if statement to include multiple intervals throughout the hour.